# When I log in as user displays my admin site, but when I log out then there's this error?

Tags: php

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['role_access'] == 1)
{
  echo '<ul><li><a href="admin/index.php">Admin Site<i class="icon-cogs"></i></a></ul></li>';
}
```

but when I log out then there's this error?
`Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\Xampp\htdocs\xampp\site\includes\menu.php on line 73`

Can not make it to do nothing when i log out? 
It will only remove the Admin site when i log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['role_access'] == 1)
```

Try like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['role_access']) && $_SESSION['user']['role_access'] == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['role_access'])== 1)
```